# Google code search - missed languages

Tags: xaml, powershell, code-search

This is very odd, but I don't see neither PowerShell nor XAML among supported languages
http://www.google.com/codesearch/advanced_code_search ?!

How can I filter results for that languages?

Comment: Did you try to click on the link next to the language list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Codesearch FAQ:](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/faq_codesearch.html#langs)

> What programming languages do you support?
>
> The Advanced Code Search page lists
>   the programming languages we're able
>   to detect. But even if your language
>   of choice isn't on there, you can
>   still search for code written in that
>   language. We make as much code
>   searchable as possible, including code
>   where we can't detect the language.
>   When we're able to detect the
>   programming language for a file, we
>   indicate that in the search results,
>   and you can restrict your search to
>   code written in that language.
>
> If we're not detecting a language you
>   care about, the `file:` operator can be
>   useful to search for files with a
>   specific extension. For example, you
>   could restrict your search to files
>   with a `.x` or `.abc` extension with a
>   query like `myquery file:\.(x|abc)$`. If
>   we're not detecting a language you
>   think is important, be sure to let us
>   know.